# How to update Interface declaration from Retrofit to Retrofit 2

Tags: android, api, retrofit, retrofit2

I got an Interface written using Retrofit 1.9 like below:

```
@PATCH("/meetings/{" + MEETING_ID + "}/extend")
    void patchExtendMeeting(
        @Header(AUTHORIZATION) String accessToken,
        @Path(MEETING_ID) Integer meetingId,
        @Query("duration") Integer duration,
        Callback<ExtendMeetingResponse> cb
    );
```

I tried to use the new format introduced in Retrofit 2.0 like that below:

```
@PATCH("/meetings/{" + MEETING_ID + "}/extend")
Call<ExtendMeetingResponse> patchExtendMeeting()
```

I just not really sure where those @path, @query should be in the new format. Searched all over the internet and seems like there are not many docs for retrofit2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see this? https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Comment: Yes I did but where should all the parameters like header, path, etc. goes in the new format? I couldn't find any samples with those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be where they were previously :

```
@Post("/meetings/{meetingId}/extend")
Call<ExtendMeetingResponse> patchExtendMeeting(
                                  @Header("Authorization") String accessToken,
                                  @Path("meetingId") Integer meetingId,
                                  @Query("duration") Integer duration,);
```

The short and sweet documentation provided on official page http://square.github.io/retrofit/ has been modified for retrofit 2.

Comment: So the patchExtendMeeting is still the function right? And all its parameters will be still there except the Callback, which is replaced with Call<T>? Am I right?

Comment: Yup, and you've observables too. You can also add authorization headers via interceptors. Go through https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-upgrade-guide-from-1-9 and you'll understand everything.

Comment: Yeah I did read that one but still got a bit confused. First time using Retrofit. Anyway thanks for your answer. I am going to test it now. Will come back for correct answer later if it works :)

Comment: @LongDao did it work? If yes, please consider accepting the answer or else we are here to help. :)

Comment: I was getting few other issues where I cannot test the app until now. In the project I am working on, RetrofitError is passing around and since it is removed in retrofit2, I still have lots of works to do to get the upgrading process done. I will keep you up-to-date with it. Cheers,